# HTML signature- before and after sending problem

Tags: html, css

The company i work at, reached out to me about having same e-mail signatures. I showed them the one made with Hubspot E-mail signature generator, and they liked its simplicity. So here you go... i got myself some work to do.  After i created the first signature and added it to Outlook i was not satisfied with the final outcome. Icons had a straight slash right behind them (as seen on picture).[image: Before sending]
After the mail with new signature was sent another problem occured- now the text was underlined and icons got a underline and uperline. [image: After sending].

I will include a code if anybody notices anything that messes up with my signature. And sorry for inline code- since im not the best at coding, i had to use generator.

```html
<table style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;" width="150">
                                <span style="margin-right: 20px; display: block;" class="template3__ImageContainer-sc-vj949k-0 kElCTu">
                                    <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;color:rgb(96,96,96)" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.google.com/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1681374751961000&amp;usg=AOvVaw04K29a4Cn6js5x3C18AsyN">
                                        <img role="presentation" style="max-width:130px" id="m_-2845722534025449574imageSelected0" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/779/61/png-clipart-logo-idea-cute-eagle-leaf-logo-thumbnail.png" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" width="130">
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <h2 color="#606060" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 16px; color: rgb(96, 96, 96); font-weight: 600;" class="name__NameContainer-sc-1m457h3-0 hkyYrA">
                                    <span>Gringo</span>
                                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                                    <span>Bongo</span>
                                </h2>
                                <p color="#606060" font-size="small" style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(96, 96, 96); font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px;" class="company-details__CompanyContainer-sc-j5pyy8-0 bEBXsp">
                                        <span>Marketing &amp; Sales
                                        </span>
                                </p>
                                <p color="#606060" font-size="small" style="color: rgb(96, 96, 96); margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px;" class="custom-field__CustomFieldContainer-sc-190n2f-0 a-DJBe">
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Breath GMbH
                                        </b>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td width="30">
                                <div style="width: 30px;">                                    
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td color="#407ec9" direction="vertical" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: medium none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 dcKmvZ" width="1" height="auto">                                
                            </td>
                            <td width="30">
                                <div style="width: 30px;">                                    
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <table style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: middle;" height="25">
                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;" width="30">
                                                <table style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                                <span color="#407ec9" width="11" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 hBHfIp">
                                                                    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/phone-icon-2x.png" color="#407ec9" alt="mobilePhone" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 dGVIJx" width="13">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(96, 96, 96);">
                                                <a href="tel:+12345678" color="#606060" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(96, 96, 96); font-size: 12px;" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 bibcmr">
                                                    <span>+12345678
                                                    </span>
                                                </a> | 
                                                <a href="tel:+87654321" color="#606060" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(96, 96, 96); font-size: 12px;" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 bibcmr">
                                                    <span>+87654321
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: middle;" height="25">
                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;" width="30">
                                                <table style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                                <span color="#407ec9" width="11" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 hBHfIp">
                                                                    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/email-icon-2x.png" color="#407ec9" alt="emailAddress" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 dGVIJx" width="13">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <a href="mailto:gongo.bongo@zumba.com" color="#606060" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(96, 96, 96); font-size: 12px;" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 bibcmr">
                                                    <span>gongo.bongo@zumba.com
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: middle;" height="25"><td style="vertical-align: middle;" width="30">
                                            <table style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                            <span color="#407ec9" width="11" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 hBHfIp">
                                                                <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/link-icon-2x.png" color="#407ec9" alt="website" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 dGVIJx" width="13">
                                                            </span>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <a href="https://www.google.com" color="#606060" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(96, 96, 96); font-size: 12px;" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 bibcmr">
                                                    <span>www.google.com
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: middle;" height="25">
                                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;" width="30">
                                                <table style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                                <span color="#407ec9" width="11" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 hBHfIp">
                                                                    <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/address-icon-2x.png" color="#407ec9" alt="address" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(64, 126, 201);" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 dGVIJx" width="13">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <span color="#606060" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(96, 96, 96);" class="contact-info__Address-sc-mmkjr6-3 fhjLwd">
                                                    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/UGv31234LRxKgE4E9/" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;color:rgb(96,96,96)" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://goo.gl/maps/UGv31234LRxKgE4E9/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1681368476770000&amp;usg=AOvVaw1Zw0IxQAcTVhIlxt5GHOnB">1234 Earth - Universe
                                                    </a>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 100%; font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5">                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td color="#407ec9" direction="horizontal" style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(64, 126, 201); border-left: medium none; display: block;" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 dcKmvZ" width="auto" height="1">
                                                            
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5">
                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 100%; font-size: small; font-family: Arial;" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 jWJRxL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;">
                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <span style="display: block; text-align: center;">
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.google.com" color="#ffffff" style="border-color: currentcolor; border-style: none; border-width: medium; display: inline-block; background-color: transparent; color: rgb(64, 126, 201); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 1; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 SvDt">
                        <img src="https://swipefile.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/cta-banner-offer-copy.png" role="presentation" style="text-decoration: none; max-height: 35px;" class="cta__CtaImage-sc-sq0d6i-1 hEhUgF">
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to search for similar issue since i'm still new to coding,  but no luck for now.

Comment: The code you have given does not demonstrate the problems (overline and underlines). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and check that your snippet shows the problem lines - or say in which email system(s) this problem occurs.

Comment: I added a full code now. We use MS Outlook 2021. Thanks in advance